# Search Box Missing in Suite Bar in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, uisearchbar, sharepoint-online

Everyone,

Greetings..!!

I have created Modern Team Site in SharePoint Online than, I have created 1 Test Page in Pages library.

When I opened Site Contents Search Box was shown in the SharePoint suite-bar. Please refer below image.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnhWW.png

When I opened Test Page from Pages library. Search Box was missing in the SharePoint suite-bar. Please refer below image.
[2]:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdvLR.png

Is there any way to unhide the Search Box on SharePoint Suite Bar while I am open page from pages library?

Please let me know your thoughts on the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created modern team site but the page is in classic mode (may be it is a wiki page).
In classic sharepoint site search box is at right. In modern pages and sites, it is on top.